# Why does VLC has interlacing Problems on my mac while Front Row and Quicktime play without?

Tags: macos, mac, video, vlc-media-player, front-row

When playing a DVD with my 27" iMac, there was never an issue with Front Row, I think it upscales quite nice.

Today i tried playing the same DVDs with VLC, there are severe interlacing artefact on the screen.

How does this come?
Why doesn't Front Row has those problem?
How to get rid of them in VLC (i activate de-interlacing without real success)?

--stephan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several de-interlacing "presets" (such as Mean or Blur) within VLC and some will look better than others based on the algorithms they use to work.  Try changing the de-interlacing algorithm and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Movist](http://code.google.com/p/movist/) is a good VLC alternative that might fix that problem.